# Getting layer extension info via ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I want to get file format of a layer with using **Arcpy**. I am writing a tool that needs to take raster or feature extension like SHP, TIFF etc. Which functions should i use ? 
Note: I use ArcGIS 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution! **arcpy.Describe** object can easily handle this. Here is the example same for feature and raster:

buildings is a Shapefile layer, dem is a TIFF layer and added in ArcMap

```
feature = arcpy.Describe("buildings")

print feature.extension
```

**output message : shp**

```
raster = arcpy.Describe("dem")

print raster.extension
```

**output message : tif**

Answer (score 4):

Use [os.path.splitext()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext)

```
import os

filename, ext = os.path.splitext(r'C:\temp2\out\fc10.shp')
print ext
```

[image]